Choice of the eigenbasis for the Dirac operator on $S^d$
This question is a simplified version of my previous one. I think that adding a gauge potential complicates the problem too much.
Let us consider the Dirac operator $D$ on the $d$-sphere $S^d$ with respect to the spin $1/2$ structure. I have $d=4$ in mind, but would like to think in more generality. An exact definition of the Dirac operator seems to be summarized in this note.
Then, I have two questions:

Is it possible to find a collection of smooth eigenspinors $\{ \psi_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ on $S^d$ for $D$ such that there exists a point $a \in S^d$ at which all orders of derivatives of all $\psi_n$ vanish.


At the same time, is it possible for such $\{ \psi_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to be complete? That is,
$$
\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \psi_n(x) \psi_n^\dagger(y) = \delta(x-y)I
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix on the representation space of the spinors and this equality should be understood in the sense of distributions on $S^d$.

The first question is equivalent to the possibility of having Schwartz function components for each $\psi_n$, as shown in this ME post.
Could anyone please help me? My impression is that the Dirac operator has been studied extensively from geometric perspectives, but somewhat less in the context of spectral analysis. Perhaps I am missing something here?

In general, have you ever encountered the book of Berline–Getzler–Vergne, Heat Kernels and Dirac operators? Any such account of the Atiyah–Singer index theorem from the heat-theoretic perspective is necessarily going to look at Dirac operators from the kind of perspective you have in mind. As for the spin Dirac operator on $S^n$ specifically, you might want to look at this paper by Bär and its references.

@BranimirĆaćić Thank you very much for your references. Indeed my search is by no means complete...I am still a bit concerned that my questions are too specific or peripheral to be addressed even in your suggested references.

This is a bit too long to fit as a comment.
For $d\geq 3$ there  is only one spin structure on $S^d$ thus a unique spin Dirac operator $D: C^\infty(S^+)\to C^\infty(S^-)$ where $S^\pm$ denotes the bundle of even/odd spinors.
If you choose any  complete orthonormal    system $(\psi_n)$  of $L^2(S^+)$ consisting of smooth spinors, then  the identity
$$\sum_n \psi_n(x)\otimes \psi_n(y)^\dagger=\delta(x-y)  $$
is tautologically satisfied,  but you  need to recall that the left hand side  is an operator from  $S^+_y\to S^+_x$ so  $\delta(x-y)$  should be  understood as an operator valued  distribution.
Let me define a section to be flat at $a\in S^d$ if all its partial derivatives vanish at that point. One can show that the space of smooth functions  that are flat at a point $a$ is dense  in $L^2(S^d)$. Thus, using Gram-Schmidt, you can choose the above sections $\psi_n$ to  be flat at a point $a$.
If you want  eigen-spnors you need to consider the operator
$$
\widehat{D}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & D^*\\
D & 0
\end{array}\right] :\begin{array}{c}
C^\infty(S^+)\\
\oplus \\
C^\infty(S^-)
\end{array} \to \begin{array}{c}
C^\infty(S^+)\\
\oplus \\
C^\infty(S^-)
\end{array}
$$
Then you can choose an orthonormal basis  of $L^2(S^+\oplus S^-)$ consisting of eigen-spinors of $\widehat{D}$. They cannot be flat at any point since they are real analytic.
For more about Dirac operators, check Chapter 12 of these notes.

Thank you for your information. I have a few questions about the details but they are a bit lengthy to write down in comment. So, I just sent you an email. I would be deeply grateful if you help me a bit more.
